# Generating styled text for Word

Tags: java

I want to make a program that makes it possible to generate styled microsoft Word text. To describe my use case:

1. I have a large list of links (URL's) - for the sake of this question let's say they are internet sources (that I want to reference in a report)
2. For each of these links, I want to print a string that complies with a notation standard for internet sources. Like, print a formatted, styled string like this: "Google. (2017, February). *Google Maps Android API*. Retrieved from *Google Developers*: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/"

   3. As you can image doing this by hand for a large set of links in a tedious task. I however have not found a way for me to copy the output with the text styling included.

Currently I've been thinking about making a PrintWriter which writes to a file and uses html tags so I can just copy from the generated HTML file and paste into a Word document, but ideally I would like to take out this step. I was wondering if there are alternatives to achieve what I want

Comment: apache poi has all you need to do this easily

Comment: I don't want to write the program to append the text to a Word document though, I want to have copy-pasteable text that I can paste directly into the Word document. Or is using POI the only option here?